# Small database management in C++

Tags: c++, database

I'm planning to develop a C++ application which must access (r/w) to a small database.
Some time ago I've written some code for accessing a formatted text file and I used this as database. But now I'm wondering if there exists some light weight library for c++ (linux box) which let me deal easily and with good performances with small databases.

I would like some suggestion.

Comment: what have you investigated?

Comment: If you just want a simple key/value storage that is _very_ simple to use, you check out e.g. [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/) or similar [DBM based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dbm) databases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not 100% sure whether this is as "easy" as you wish, but in my opinion SQLite (http://www.sqlite.org/) is kind of an easy-to-use solution i used to use a while ago...
hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm going to take a look about it. My "easy" must be read as "as easy as standard c++ file access is"

Comment: It's more like requests that you prepare and commit, then get back results and process as u like (as a short description)

and there are a lot of tutorials out there :)

Comment: Using a relational database like sqlite can be easier than using a flat file, or more complicated, depending on your point of view. The code is a little more complicated and you must know (or learn) SQL, however your code must only concentrate on the data and not its location within a file, no risk of corrupting the file through simple code errors, etc. Even if it's a learning curve for you, your time would be well spent to learn sqlite. Note that it's a C API, but there are many C++ wrappers for it which may make it easier for you.

Comment: sqlite seems really interesting! Is it available for Debian/Ubuntu via apt?

Comment: @the_candyman [apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev](http://theplana.wordpress.com/2007/05/11/install-sqlite3-on-ubuntu/).